# Extract substring from a blob column to make an addition to use it in subfield

Tags: mysql, regex, subquery

I want to extract the value of a column that initialy was a blob field.

So I have this SQL query :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS single_commande AS (
    SELECT o.order_id, coi.order_item_id, CONVERT(coic.adjustments_value USING utf8) AS ajustement
    FROM all_orders o
        LEFT JOIN commerce_order_item coi
            on o.order_id = coi.order_id
        LEFT JOIN commerce_order_item__adjustments coic
            on coic.entity_id = coi.order_item_id
    WHERE o.order_id = 51
);
```

Which gave me those data :

[image]

The adjustment values look like this :

> O:32:"Drupal\commerce_order\Adjustment":7:{s:7:".*.type";s:3:"tax";s:8:".*.label";s:4:"Taxe";s:9:".*.amount";O:27:"Drupal\commerce_price\Price":2:{s:9:".*.number";s:4:"4.60";s:15:".*.currencyCode";s:3:"EUR";}s:13:".*.percentage";s:3:"0.2";s:11:".*.sourceId";s:48:"tva|default|56fdce53-c1db-4ae2-8612-c3f0a4e6e4da";s:11:".*.included";b:1;s:9:".*.locked";b:0;}

And I need to extract the **number** value (here, *4.6*) from this string, to this on each row and sum all those number to get a total.

I need this total to be used in another query, this one:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS traiteur_commandes AS (
    SELECT o.order_id     AS `CommandeID`,
           (SUM OF ALL ADJUSTMENT BY order_id  AS `TotalHT` /* to calculate */
    FROM all_orders o
        ...
    ORDER BY o.order_id
);
```

In the end, I'll remove the *CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS single_commande* because I'll need to use subquery, this is just for test.

I think I have to do something like

```
SELECT sum(CONVERT(coic.adjustments_value USING utf8 /* DO SOMETHING TO GET THE VALUE */ )) AS ajustment
```

Maybe I can extract the value with a regex of something like `REGEXP '.*Price";s:[0-9]+:"number".*'` (i'm working on the regex for now)

Any idea if this is the best way or i'm totally wrong ?

**EDIT** : this is from the drupal commerce module, so I can't alter the field in the database. Also, I can't use php or something else, I can only export data through MySQL.

Comment: You should store the price in a column by itself if you want to use it as a discrete value in SQL queries.

Comment: This column is for the VAT, which is automaticaly calculated, I can't change the database since it's from a module

Comment: It looks like the string format for a serialized PHP object. You could fetch the whole value into the PHP client, deserialize it, and then access the `number` as a field. Do this in a loop for all the rows you want, and calculate a sum in the client.

Comment: Yes, it is from a PHP class. Unfortunatly, this data have to be extract only from an sql script, I can't use PHP, I would've done it otherwise :)

Comment: Maybe there is a solution using [REGEXP_SUBSTR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) but I suppose you have to use an outdated version of MySQL as well.

Comment: I can use this function, my mysql version is > 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Here's a solution for MySQL. Based on your comments, I believe you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These two database products are not compatible.**

I tested by setting a variable `@s` to the PHP serialized object you show. You would use your `ajustement` column as you query your temp table.

```
set @s = 'O:32:"Drupal\\commerce_order\\Adjustment":7:{s:7:"..type";s:3:"tax";s:8:"..label";s:4:"Taxe";s:9:"..amount";O:27:"Drupal\\commerce_price\\Price":2:{s:9:"..number";s:4:"4.60";s:15:"..currencyCode";s:3:"EUR";}s:13:"..percentage";s:3:"0.2";s:11:"..sourceId";s:48:"tva|default|56fdce53-c1db-4ae2-8612-c3f0a4e6e4da";s:11:"..included";b:1;s:9:".*.locked";b:0;}'
```

First use a REGEXP_SUBSTR() to extract the Price object.

```
mysql> select regexp_substr(@s,
  '"Drupal\\\\commerce_price\\\\Price":2:\\{[^}]*\\}', 1, 1, 'c') as PriceObject;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| PriceObject                                                                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "Drupal\commerce_price\Price":2:{s:9:"..number";s:4:"4.60";s:15:"..currencyCode";s:3:"EUR";} |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Based on that, use another to extract the "..number" field and its following value.

```
mysql> select regexp_substr(
  regexp_substr(@s,
    '"Drupal\\\\commerce_price\\\\Price":2:\\{[^}]*\\}', 1, 1, 'c'),
  '"..number";[^;]*;') as number;
+------------------------+
| number                 |
+------------------------+
| "..number";s:4:"4.60"; |
+------------------------+
```

Based on that, use another to extract the value.

```
mysql> select regexp_substr(
  regexp_substr(
    regexp_substr(@s,
      '"Drupal\\\\commerce_price\\\\Price":2:\\{[^}]*\\}', 1, 1, 'c'),
    '"..number";[^;]*;'),
  '"[[:digit:].]+"') as number;
+--------+
| number |
+--------+
| "4.60" |
+--------+
```

Then strip the quotes and cast as a decimal number.

```
mysql> select cast(json_unquote(
  regexp_substr(
    regexp_substr(
      regexp_substr(@s,
        '"Drupal\\\\commerce_price\\\\Price":2:\\{[^}]*\\}', 1, 1, 'c'),
      '"..number";[^;]*;'),
    '"[[:digit:].]+"')) as decimal(9,2)) as number;
+--------+
| number |
+--------+
|   4.60 |
+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have an error on the last regexp_substring **Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function**

Comment: Removing *, 1, 1, 'c'* "fix" this, guess you helped me with the biggest part, thanks ! . Do you have any why I get this error "truncated incorrect decimal value: ''" ?

Comment: You must be using MariaDB, not MySQL. MariaDB's implementation of REGEXP_SUBSTR() is different from MySQL 8.0, and it only accepts two arguments. So the regexp is not matching the same as my implementation. You need to think of MariaDB as a different product from MySQL. They are not compatible.

Comment: Oh okey, sorry indeed, i'm using MariaDB 1.04.11... Sorry, should've seen that.

Comment: As my question and your answer were for mysql, of course I accept your asnwer.

Comment: Well, the technique shown above might help you get started doing something similar with MariaDB's implementation of regular expressions.

Comment: Had to chage **'"..number";[^;]*;'** to **'"*number";[^;]*;'** . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a PHP "serialized" object.  If so, read the blob int, say $x `unserialize($x)`, then use var_dump or print_r to see what it looks like to PHP.  Then simply reach into `$x` to grab whatever field you need.

```
__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
(
    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => Drupal\commerce_order\Adjustment
    [..?type] => tax
    [..?label] => Taxe
    [..?amount] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
        (
            [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => Drupal\commerce_price\Price
            [..?number] => 4.60
            [..?currencyCode] => EUR
        )

    [..?percentage] => 0.2
    [..?sourceId] => tva|default|56fdce53-c1db-4ae2-8612-c3f0a4e6e4da
    [..?included] => 1
    [.*.locked] => 
)
```

(I added "?" to make the strings long enough; I don't know the cause of that problem.)